# AWS S3 GetBucketLifecycleConfiguration access denied

Tags: amazon-web-services

We have 2 AWS accounts "A" and "B". We setup an S3 bucket in account "B" and his ACL says the following:

```
Access To Your Account     List Objects    Write Objects    Read Bucket Permissions    Write Bucket Permissions 
"B"                        "YES"           "YES"            "YES"                       "YES"

Access for other AWS accounts     List Objects    Write Objects    Read Bucket Permissions    Write Bucket Permissions 
"A"                               "YES"           "YES"            "YES"                       "YES"
```

Now I'm trying to do the following:

```
aws s3api get-bucket-lifecycle-configuration --bucket <name>
```

with the AWS credentials from a User in account "A". However, I receive the error

```
An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the GetBucketLifecycleConfiguration operation: Access Denied
```

But shouldn't all users from account "A" have access to the bucket?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After granting the cross-account permissions on the bucket by the owner (account A), the *administrator* of the account B inherits all the permissions, but all other users of account B need to have the bucket policy attached explicitly by their administrator.

This means that you need to log in to the console of account B as the administrator and grant the chosen user this inline policy (change the bucket name):

```
{
   "Version": "2012-10-17",
   "Statement": [
      {
         "Sid": "Example",
         "Effect": "Allow",
         "Action": [
            "s3:*"
         ],
         "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::MYBUCKETNAME"
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

(`"s3:*"` grants the full access, you can change it to some more limited policy if you need)

The whole workflow of granting such perimissions is described in the [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-walkthroughs-managing-access-example2.html) example.

Comment: It is not working if the action is "s3: GetBucketLifecycleConfiguration" but works when the action is "s3:Get*". By any chace, anyone knows the correct action for this?

Comment: @ckreddy The correct action is `s3:GetLifecycleConfiguration`. Documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_GetBucketLifecycleConfiguration.html

Answer (score 1):

When you use ACL's to allow cross account access on S3, these are the only permissions that an IAM user in account A will inherit:

1. put-object, delete-object
2. list-bucket
3. get-bucket-acl
4. put-bucket-acl

Any API calls outside the above 4 will result in an Access Denied error. If your use case is to allow full S3 access for an IAM user in account A, you would need to do the following:

1. Whitelist the IAM user from Account A to have s3:* permissions on bucket policy in Account B
2. In the IAM user policy of Account A, make sure he has s3:* or specific permissions to the bucket located in Account B.

Alternatively, you can grant root access to Account A on bucket policy in account B, following which the permissions from root can be delegated to all IAM users in Account A.